# Should there be a way to share short stories?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to share short stories or other writings for critique?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we encourage users to give samples of their writing for critique?](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/58/should-we-encourage-users-to-give-samples-of-their-writing-for-critique)

Answer (score 5):

The chat would be perfect for this.  The parent site would not be.

Comment: If the question is something like "How do I improve this", followed by a text dump, that seems like it should be closed.  I hesitate to say it's out of scope exactly, but knowing writers, if we started that precedent, it would quickly take over the site.  On the other hand, an on-topic question *supported* by a writing sample seems perfectly okay to me.